# Какой второй аргумент написать в array_column

Tags: php

Всем привет.

учу php новичок короче поэтому прошу помидоров не кидать.

У меня в админке `php` кидает такую ошибку

```
Warning: array_column() expects at least 2 parameters, 
1 given in  и путь к папке и строка в котороя вызвала данную ошибку
```

Пробовал добавить вторым аргументом *имя таблицы БД,*

Пробовал добавить **NULL**

Ничего не получалсья .

И также не понял что написано в документации `php`

Вот мой код

```
 <?php
     $connection;
     $queryApproved = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments  WHERE admin_panel_id='$id' AND status='ON'";
     $execute = mysqli_query($connection,$queryApproved);
     $rows_approved = mysqli_fetch_array($execute);
     $total_approved = array_column($rows_approved);
             if($total_approved > 0){          
          ?>
<span class="badge float-right badge-success"><?php  echo $total_approved; ?></span>

     <?php } ?>
```

Этот код из БД достает комментарии которые утверждены админом и показывает их в админ панели...

Помогите очень прошу что мне написать вторым аргументом чтобы сработало а то уже два дня ничего не могу сделать.

И курс который я смотрю старый и да я в курсе что то что я написал наверху некоторые из этих методов уже устарели проста добью этот курс потом начну изучать **PDO**

Comment: Перед `$total_approved = array_column($rows_approved);` сделайте `var_dump($rows_approved); exit;` и покажите результат, мы вам поможем

Comment: @Manitikyl спасибо большое .Сделал вот результат.  array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "0" ["COUNT(*)"]=> string(1) "0" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените `$total_approved = array_column($rows_approved);`

на `$total_approved = $rows_approved['COUNT(*)'];`

Можно сделать элегантнее:

`$queryApproved = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments  WHERE admin_panel_id='$id' AND status='ON'";`
вставить тут `SELECT COUNT(*) as total`

и тогда:

`$total_approved = $rows_approved['total'];`